# Move changesets to different machine

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I am using TortoiseHg and I have some changesets in draft mode and now due to some reasons I am in a situation to use a different machine.

So, is there any way to like take a backup and restore my changesets on a new machine?

Since I'm not sure about fetching the draft mode changsets on a different machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can** do this regardless of the [*phase*](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Phases) (public/draft/secret) of the changeset - I do it all the time at my work using [patches](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.0/patches.html).

<s>For this you will need the "[mq](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MqExtension)" extension (installed but not enabled by default) turned on from your settings.</s> (*actually, you can do this without mq*)

Take the following steps, working your way from the first `draft` changeset (i.e. the one whose parent is `public`) to the last `draft` changeset (i.e. the one which is at the [head](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Head)):

1. Right click on a *single* changeset in the source repository and select `Export/Copy patch`, the output of which you can paste into a text file. Repeat this *n* times to get the patches you want to copy.
2. Transfer those text files to the other machine, then select `Repository/Import` on the target repository then *import* the changeset. Repeat this (in the order the changesets were exported) to recreate the same history as on the source repository.

Answer (score 1):

If you already committed, but not pushed the changesets, you can just copy the **.hg** direcotry to the other machine. If you have uncommitted changes, you have to copy the entire directory where your repository and **.hg** directory is in.

And no, you can't fetch draft mode changes on another machine. They are available once you pushed (status "public").